# How to display some field name instead for primary key in other Model in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models and i am using foreignkey in model.

```
class Student:
    book            = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

When i show the student list then in last column , i see the primary key e,g 2 or 3.

But i want that instaed of  primary key i should be able to see Book Name. how can i do it

Comment: Which list?  In the admin? In a template?  Add your `admin.py` or template to the question.

Comment: no not in admin but when i use   `list = model.objects.all()` then loop over fields

Comment: `print student.book.the_field_you_want_to_print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd really recommend is to not use get_fields, but what you could do if you must use it is:

```
{% for field, value in student.get_fields %}
    {% if field.name %}
        {% field.name %}
    {% else %}
        {% field %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks buddy that was clever solution but why i should not use get_fields . what else i can use because i need to shows all columns in list view

Answer (score 1):

add `__unicode__` method to Book model
def `__unicode__`(self):
return self.name

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should define the `__unicode__` method for the `Book` model.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode

Comment: I my template i am displaying all table fields with values using this `{% for field, value in student.get_fields %}` that part is showing numerical pk . i am not talking about Form

Comment: May be you should some method other than `get_fields`. Please provide more information in question.